# How do I make a webRequest Event Page that only listens for events when a flag is set?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making an extension that can be ON or OFF, which I can check via a flag stored in local data.

When ON, I want to listen for all webRequests and redirect them like so:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(

  // callback
  function(info) {
    console.log("Got request: " + info.url + "\n Going to redirect");
    return {redirectUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("redirect.html")};
  },

  // filters
  {
    urls: [
      "<all_urls>"
    ]
  },

  // extraInfoSpec
  ["blocking"]);
```

But when OFF I do not want the event to fire at all. Ideally when OFF I wouldn't even be listening to events (if that would cut down on performance overhead in any significant way).  One option I see is checking the flag in my callback function and simply not redirecting if OFF, but that still has the event being handled. As I understand it, the event will not be handled if the RequestFilter does not pass. Can I modify the RequestFilter to also check my ON/OFF boolean flag before trying to handle the event? Or is the RequestFilter only meant for checking URLs, headers, etc.?

Also my main reasoning for wanting to only handle events when ON is that it seems like a needless performance hit to try to handle EVERY webRequest - even if briefly. Would an immediate flag checking in the callback function not make any noticeable impact on performance anyway?

I am new to Chrome Extension dev and webdev in general, so if there is a much cleaner/easier way of doing this then please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[RequestFilters](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#type-RequestFilter)** do not allow you to specify arbitrary conditions (such as if a flag is set). You can un-register the listener using **[removeListener()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events.html#method-Event-removeListener)** whenever the flag is set to OFF and register it back when the flag is set to ON. E.g.:

```
function myListener(...) {...}

function setEnabled(enabled) {
    localStorage.enabled = enabled ? 'ON' : 'OFF';
    if (enabled) {
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(myListener);
    } else {
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(myListener);
    }
}

function isEnabled() {
    return (localStorage.enabled !== 'OFF');   // <-- 'ON' by default
}

setEnabled(isEnabled());
```

Comment: Ahh of course, I should have thought to look for the ability to remove listeners. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

The [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) API cannot be used on [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html).
If you implement [ExpertSystem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296780/how-do-i-make-a-webrequest-event-page-that-only-listens-for-events-when-a-flag-i/21297238#21297238), then your extension won't add overhead to requests, but it will still waste memory (because using the `webRequest` API implies that you're using [background pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html). These pages always remain active even when the extension appears to do nothing).

The [`chrome.declarativeWebRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest.html) is similar to the webRequest API, except that its API is declarative, allowing it to be used on [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html) as well. The only downside of the API is that it is currently only enabled on the [beta or dev channel](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel). It will eventually be available on the stable channel though, probably within a few releases.

The following example shows how to redirect any URL whose host contains "google" ("google.com", "www.google.nl", but NOT "notgoogle.com") to a page within your extension:

```
var rules = [{
    id: 'redirect-to-my-extension',
    conditions: [
        new chrome.declarativeWebRequest.RequestMatcher({
            url: {
                hostContains: '.google.'
            }
        })
    ],
    actions: [
        new chrome.declarativeWebRequest.RedirectRequest({
            redirectUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL('redirect.html')
        })
    ]
}];

// Whenever you're ready...
chrome.declarativeWebRequest.onRequest.addRules(rules);

// To disable the rules, simply remove the rules (by the previously specified id)
var ruleIds = rules.map(function(rule) { return rule.id; });
chrome.declarativeWebRequest.onRequest.removeRules(ruleIds);
```

This is merely an example. The declarativeWebRequest API has lots of other ways to construct conditions or actions, just take a look at the [reference documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest.html) and [URL filters](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events.html#type-UrlFilter).

Comment: Interesting, thank you for clarifying that and thank you for the sample code! I will probably work from the beta channel in that case.

Comment: half way through 2016 and this is still in beta :/

Comment: @Neil There were plans to either remove it (https://crbug.com/586636), or to investigate the possibility to revive it and bring it to stable (no public posts, this was in a private mail conversation).

Comment: @RobW, Is there anything that declarativeWebRequest can do that can't be done by the normal webRequest in bg?

Comment: I would like to point out to anyone who sees this that, according to the page linked in this answer, "[the declarativeWebRequest] API is currently on hold, without concrete plans to move to stable."

So, yeah, extremely disappointing, with no alternatives that don't come with backgroundPages downsides.